# Weird listview's separator

Tags: react-native

I use normal Listview from react native. The code is as below. However, it shows weird separator between 5th and 6th items.

"react": "16.3.1",

"react-native": "0.55.2",

```
<ListView
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    renderRow={this._renderView}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
>


_renderView(rowData, sid, rowID){
return(
  <View
    style={{flex: 1, height: window.height*0.12, backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'center', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#eee'}}>
   ...
  </View>
)
}
```

`

[image]

Comment: `ListView` have been deprecated, try `FlatList` and check if the issue still occurs

Comment: replaced listview with flatlist but not solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, it was caused by passing empty data on one of the items to my dataSource. That resulted in rendering an empty component wich ends up putting two bottom lines on top of each other (because there is no content to separate them). Try checking your dataSource for empty or invalid items.